# Error reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance after add library 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.8'

Tags: ios, swift

In my project an additional library will be added to work with advertising.

error show when after I add library '`Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK`', '~> 7.8' with pods

```
 version Xcode 8.2.1
 Deployment target 9.0
```

I created a test project that added this library to it, everything works there

Crash occurs in the `ViewController` after the `viewWillAppear` method

```
viewDidAppear
```

don't call

my Podfile

[image]

my error

[image]

Comment: I don't think crash is nothing to do withthe pods.... try adding an exception break point and reproduce the crash.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/1825618

Comment: share som related code . where crashed your code.?

Comment: please post your view controller code to debug/understand.

Comment: @Bluewings error in this line         GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-pub-8897707692461041~208566932")
AppDelegate, import GoogleMobileAds, method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @Bilal error in this line GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-pub-8897707692461041~208566932") AppDelegate, import GoogleMobileAds, method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tried nothing to help and decided to create a project and quietly migrate and constantly build the project in order to understand what's wrong, so transfer the data from the introjection to a new project and again the same crash appeared.

It turned out that in this case `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` `string =" whatsapp ".`

If suddenly someone will encounter this problem, then "climb" into the info sheet and check the item that I indicated above. All good.